# How to insert data to JTable based on the search box?

Tags: java

I'm currently working with my first GUI project for our school subject. But I'm having trouble with JTable and the Search box.

I can search the data from the table, however, when I am clicking the row where the data that I'm searching for is located, the data that it will read is still coming from the recent table, disregarding the data that I've searched.

This is my code for Displaying the Data from Database into JTable

```
'public class AddMembers extends javax.swing.JFrame {
java.util.Date date;

java.util.Date sqldate;
TableRowSorter<TableModel> rowSorter;
 Connection conn=null; 
Statement stat=null;
ResultSet rs=null;
PreparedStatement pst=null;
public AddMembers() {

    initComponents();
    setTitle("Membership Form");
    setSize (1544,900);
    connect();
}
  public void connect(){
try{
    String user="root";
    String pass="";
        conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://127.0.01:3306/church?serverTimezone=UTC",user,pass);
        stat=conn.createStatement();
        rs=stat.executeQuery("Select * from person Order by First_Name asc");
        Person.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

          }
          catch(Exception e){
                  System.out.println(e);
          }'
```

This is my code for the search box

```
    private void SearchtextKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                      


    String text = Searchtext.getText();
    rowSorter= new TableRowSorter<>(Person.getModel());
    Person.setRowSorter(rowSorter);
    if (text.trim().length() == 0) {
    connect();
    } else {
    rowSorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + text));

    }



}
```

This is my code for the JTable mouseclicked

```
    private void PersonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                    

    // TODO add your handling code here:

    model= (DefaultTableModel)Person.getModel();
    int selectedrow=Person.getSelectedRow();
    Personid.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedrow, 0).toString());
    fname.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedrow, 1).toString());
    mi.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedrow, 2).toString());
    lname.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedrow, 3).toString());
    Type1.setSelectedItem(model.getValueAt(selectedrow, 6));
    deptid.setText(model.getValueAt(selectedrow, 7).toString());
    contactnum .setText(model.getValueAt(selectedrow, 8).toString());
    brgy1.setSelectedItem(model.getValueAt(selectedrow, 9).toString());

    String s  =model.getValueAt(selectedrow, 5).toString();
    String  dt=model.getValueAt(selectedrow, 4).toString();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    try {
    d.setDate(sdf.parse(dt));
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(AddMembers.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    if( s.equals("Male")){
        m.setSelected(true);
        f.setSelected(false);
    }
    else if(s.equals("Female")){
        f.setSelected(true);
        m.setSelected(false);
    }
    connect();


    }
```

Comment: So, there's a difference between "view" and "model" data.  When you filter the table, the "view" doesn't modify the the "model", it simply creates row mappings to the rows in the model it wants to continue displaying.  This will change the row index you use to access the model. You want to use [`JTable#convertRowIndexToModel `](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel(int)) which will give the the row index you can use to get the data from the model.

Comment: Wow thanks @MadProgrammer ! You really helped me.